# Load php loop with Ajax request (or similar Javascript solutions)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I try to figure out how to load just a small piece of data (php loop) with xmlhttp request.

The function I'm using is working perfectly, however I would like to load only php loop which is in the file "gallery.php":

```
function refreshData(){

                  var display = document.getElementById("content");
                  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                  xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ?>gallery/");
                  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  xmlhttp.send();

                  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                      display.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                    } else {
                      display.innerHTML = "Loading...";
                    };
                  }
                }
```

I have a post and I'm try to load the images binded to this post. The loop in the gallery.php is here:

```
<?php $images = get_attached_media( 'image' );

            foreach($images as $image) { ?>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID,'full'); ?>"/>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

I want to load this loop with images after the button is clicked with xmlhttp request, but I do need a help how to request the dynamic data.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While working with ajax on wordpress themes, you should use wordpress ajax action hooks https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

so for example:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_galleryimage', 'get_galleryimage' );

function get_galleryimage() {
// than here you put the code to get the images of the given posts, you 
//should send post id from the js  

// Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
wp_die();
}
```

you don't need to make a page for that, with the use of hooks your ajax call will be on this url, homeurl../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_galleryimage

Comment: Thanks but I've dissabled a lot of stuff included jQuery on the frontend, so basically I can't use this solution. That's why I am trying to figure out how to make an xmlhttp request to get the data.

Comment: Still you can use this, just register this hook and function and than send xmlhttp request to that url /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_galleryimage  if your function name  hooked is get_galleryimage()  this hook has nothing to do with what you are doing with js.           And than on that function you should send post id on which gallery is and than loop through it, i can send you sample code if needed

Comment: Thanks Sandeep Shrestha, this solution worked perfectly!